# Restangular.one('places', 123).getList('venues') table relationship

Tags: angularjs, rest, restangular

```
Restangular.one('places', 123).getList('venues') // GET /places/123/venues
```

In my understanding places and venues is a database table, and what i only understand in the above code is that it will look in the table 'places' which have the id of '123'.

Does `.getList('venues')` will query the 'venues' table that have the referenced id of 'places/123'?

Answer (score 0):

Neither Restangular nor REST in general make any assumptions *how* resources are stored on the server. You cannot derive any reliable information about your database model from the resource URI.

However, your guess that "places" maps to a parent table and that "venues" maps to a lookup table *could* be right. This is the way most developers would model their data when using a relational database.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. but when i tried this its not working. i created two tables, ex. accounts and messages. i put an accountid in the messages table that references the id in accounts table and when i try to GET /accounts/id/messages i get error 404.